# Normalization vs Standadization

Tags: normalization, standardization

Of the two best known techniques for feature scaling in Machine Learning:

- **Normalizing** a feature to a $[0, 1]$ range, through $x - x_{min} \over x_{max} - x_{min}$

or

- **Standardizing** the feature (also referred to as z-score), through $x - μ \over σ$, where $μ$ is the mean and $σ$ is the standard deviation.

Is there any reason to prefer one over the other? Does any one outperform the other when used with certain algorithms?

Comment: It depends on the objective.

Comment: @user2974951 Is there any case where one is preferred over the other? Or does one have any useful properties compared to the other?

Comment: Your comment makes me believe this is a possible duplicate of [Is it a good practice to always scale/normalize data for machine learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189652/is-it-a-good-practice-to-always-scale-normalize-data-for-machine-learning)

Comment: @FransRodenburg The author asks *which feature scaling to perform*, while the question you referenced is about *whether or not to use feature scaling*. I think it's a valid question.

Comment: @JohnDoe I realise the difference in titles, but if you read the accepted answer you'll see that it is more similar than it might seem at first.