# MinMaxScaler() for data with many zero values

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, normalization

Would it be the right approach to apply MinMaxScaler() to a data column that contains many zeros, for example [0.0 3.1 0.0 0.0 8.2 0.0 2.5 15.85 0.0 0.0 0.0] if after scaling all these values ​​where there are zeros are filled. Will this affect the selection of features?

Comment: see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189652/is-it-a-good-practice-to-always-scale-normalize-data-for-machine-learning) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-conducting-multiple-regression-when-should-you-center-your-predictor-varia)