# Normalization ,standardization, or do nothing

Tags: data-transformation, data-mining, normalization, standardization

I have medical data with max value 500 along with values like age and binary values for sex (0 or 1).
I will use clustering to find the number of clusters. 
Which is the best approach among three.Normalize each coloumn,standardize with z scores or do nothing. 
For z-scores i heard that he data should be a normal distribution,so should i box- cox them first?
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either do Normalization or standardization. You cannot do clustering properly with mixed attributes (continuous and binary) without the features scaling.
You can check the following link as well:
[Is it important to scale data before clustering?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89809/is-it-important-to-scale-data-before-clustering)

Comment: and i have to standardize every coloumn separated ,right?

Comment: Yes, that should be the way.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Z-scores you should first be sure there is no outside standard population for converting them to z-scores.  For example, children's height and weight are sometimes converted to z-scores, but researchers use the World Health Organization (WHO) dataset to do this, so the computed Z-score result is where each subject in the researcher's datatset would fall on the WHO distribution, if they were a member of that distribution.